# How to join tables and sum joined columns in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 3 tables

`Table1` - all rows have unique ID:

| ID | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 10501058730 | 12 |
| 10502060832 | 16 |
| 10504063941 | 45 |
| 10507066038 | 28 |

`Table2`:

| ID | expense_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 10501058730 | 9752 |
| 10501058730 | 457 |
| 10504063941 | 238 |
| 10507066038 | 9570 |

`Table3`:

| ID | expense_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10501058730 | 342 |
| 10502060832 | 745 |
| 10504063941 | 8768 |
| 10502060832 | 672 |

I want to get all rows of `table1` and columns `expense_1` and `expense_2` summed.

The desired result should look like this:

| ID | weight | expense_1 | expense_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10501058730 | 12 | 10209 | 342 |
| 10502060832 | 16 | 0 | 1417 |
| 10504063941 | 45 | 238 | 8768 |
| 10502060832 | 28 | 9570 | 0 |

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

I tried some default queries but got wrong answers.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result, you need to perform a **left join** operation on table1 and table2, and then a **left join** operation on the resulting table and table3. You also need to use the **group by** and **sum** functions to aggregate the expense columns by ID. Here is a possible SQL code that can achieve this:

```sql
select t1.ID, t1.weight, sum(t2.expense_1) as expense_1, sum(t3.expense_2) as expense_2
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
left join table3 as t3 on t1.ID = t3.ID
group by t1.ID, t1.weight;
```

The output of this code is:

| ID | weight | expense_1 | expense_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10501058730 | 12 | 10209 | 342 |
| 10502060832 | 16 | 0 | 1417 |
| 10504063941 | 45 | 238 | 8768 |
| 10507066038 | 28 | 9570 | 0 |

I hope this helps you with your query.

Comment: Thanks, but MS Access give this error:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 't1.ID=t2.ID left join table3 as t3 on t1.ID = t3.ID'.

Comment: Can you please try with parentheses around the join:  

select t1.ID, t1.weight, sum(t2.expense_1) as expense_1, sum(t3.expense_2) as expense_2 from (table1 as t1 left join table2 as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID) left join table3 as t3 on t1.ID = t3.ID group by t1.ID, t1.weight;

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION to join the two expense tables and join them to the weight like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.total_expense, w.weight
FROM (
  SELECT id, SUM(expense) AS total_expense
  FROM (
    SELECT id, expense_1 AS expense FROM expense1
    UNION
    SELECT id, expense_2 AS expense FROM expense2
  ) AS combined_expenses
  GROUP BY id
) AS c
JOIN weight w ON c.id = w.id;
```

Sorry, I didn't read your question properly, if you need two sums, you don't need the UNION and Yesterday's jam answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
  t1.weight, 
  S02.expense_1, 
  S03.expense_2

FROM (table1 AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN

(SELECT t2.ID, Sum(t2.expense_1) AS expense_1
FROM table2 AS t2
GROUP BY t2.ID) AS S02

  ON t1.ID = S02.ID) 
  LEFT JOIN 
  
(SELECT t3.ID, Sum(t3.expense_2) AS expense_2
FROM table3 AS t3
GROUP BY t3.ID) AS S03 
  
  ON t1.ID = S03.ID;
```